# Crash in JIT compiler of .Net (clrjit.dll)

Tags: .net, crash, jit

Parts of my software is written in C++.NET (most of the code is written in C++) and everything runs perfectly on my own server and the customer's servers.
However, on some of the customer's servers, the software crashes in `clrjit.dll`.  Top of the call stack looks like this:

```
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x68
clrjit!fatal+0x31 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\jit64\stubs.c @ 129]
clrjit!assert+0xa [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\jit64\debug.c @ 1054]
clrjit!THX_NColMdGetInitialRegisters+0xac2a3 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\jit64\amd64\ncolormd.c @ 400]
clrjit!THX_NColDeterminePhysregUseable+0x72f [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\jit64\ncolor.c @ 3785]
```

It looks like this is a crash in the JIT compiler of .NET, not in my code.

- Is this a known issue?
- Something that only appears with this specific .NET version (4.0.30319.36627)?
- Can this be caused by an incorrect installation of .NET?
- Might this be a symptom of a virus or malware?
- Or can this be caused by an error in my code?

When looking at the crash dump files, I see that the `clrjit.dll` contains a normal version number, but suffixed by the text "`built by: FX452RTMLDR_B`".  I don't see this in the properties tab of the DLL's on my system.

Since the problem only appears on some servers and not on others, I suspect an incorrect installation of .Net, but I'm not sure.  Any suggestions?

Comment: is that .NET 4.0? I hate to say it, but: wasn't that end-of-life about 4 and a half years ago? which means: a) yes, it is entirely possible that there is a long-resolved bug, and b) you won't really get much direct support for your existing 4.0 usage, other than guidance to update